# Adding a field without the field_ prefix (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups, entities

I am using the organic groups module which adds a field with machine name: group_audience to the user entity which can be seen at:

```
/config/people/accounts/fields
```

Somehow after install some other modules, this field disappeared.  I would like to add it back the field's machine name was simply group_audience instead of field_group_audience.

When I try and create a new field with the Drupal 7 interface builder it always prepends field_ to any field that is create.  How can I create a field that does not have the field_ prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Organic Groups module has a [nifty API method](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_create_field/7) for this. You just need to do a:

```
og_create_field(OG_AUDIENCE_FIELD, 'user', 'user');
```

This first checks if the field exists and creates it if it doesn't, then checks if an instance of the field has been attached to the *user* entity and creates it if it doesn't.

You can check [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53474/using-drupal-7-functions-in-external-files/53475#53475) answer out to understand where and how you can run this snippet from.

Answer (score 2):

You can add fields without prefixes  with [drush field-create](http://www.drush.org/#field-create) command or by using [Remove field name prefix](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_name_prefix_remove) module.